# Deserializing JSON Response from unity's Firebask SDK Error

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

Currently i am using unity to post comments that get saved in a firebase RTDB.

here is the posting code:

```
Comment NewComment = new Comment("User1", "Great App!");
Dictionary<string, System.Object> childUpdates = new 
Dictionary<string, System.Object>();
childUpdates["NewUpdate2"] = NewComment.ToDict();
_database.GetReference("DumbData").UpdateChildrenAsync(childUpdates);
```

which works well and posts the data to Firebase

For reference here is the Comment Class.

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Comment
{
    public Comment(string Name,string Content)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Content = Content;
    }
    public Dictionary<string,System.Object> ToDict()
    {
        Dictionary<string, System.Object> result = new Dictionary<string, System.Object>();
        result["Name"] = this.Name;
        result["Content"] = this.Content;
        return result;
    }
    public string Name;
    public string Content;
}
```

and the firebase registers the data received correctly.
[image]

but then when receiving the data, i would do

```
var dataSnapShot = await _database.GetReference("DumbData").GetValueAsync();
var Results  = dataSnapShot.GetRawJsonValue();
var temp= JsonUtility.FromJson<Dictionary<string, Comment>>(Results)
```

but the thing is the FromJSON function returns Nulls everywhere , although the JSON is received correctly matching the structure on Firebase, for reference, the Results variable above looks like this:

```
{"NewUpdate":{"Content":"Great App!","Name":"User1"},"NewUpdate2":{"Content":"Great App!","Name":"User2"}}
```

so that's where i am stuck, i cannot deseriazlize the response back to be able to use it.

Comment: `Dictionary` is not (de)serializable by `JsonUtility`. Rather use e.g. [Newtonsoft .NET JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

Answer (score 0):

JsonUtility is very limited with nested objects, dictionaries, etc.

I'll recommend you to use another library for handling JSON serialize and deserialize, you can use [Newtonsoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) library for example, or use my own [JsonManager](https://github.com/EricBatlle/SimpleUnityUtils/tree/master/Assets/Simple_JsonManager) (the repo includes and example of how it works and how to use it).

**Newtonsoft:**

Serialize:

```
Product product = new Product();
product.Name = "Apple";
product.Expiry = new DateTime(2008, 12, 28);
product.Sizes = new string[] { "Small" };

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);
// {
//   "Name": "Apple",
//   "Expiry": "2008-12-28T00:00:00",
//   "Sizes": [
//     "Small"
//   ]
// }
```

Deserialize:

```
string json = @"{
  'Name': 'Bad Boys',
  'ReleaseDate': '1995-4-7T00:00:00',
  'Genres': [
    'Action',
    'Comedy'
  ]
}";

Movie m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Movie>(json);

string name = m.Name;
// Bad Boys
```

So in your particular case that deserialize is not working, you should do something like:

```
Dictionary<string, Comment> temp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Comment>>(json);
```